# Kubernets dashboard not creating pod

Tags: kubernetes

Why is this not creating pod? I want to test the dashboard but I need to edit the port type first as suggested on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2807#issuecomment-568939435). For some reason it isn't creating any pods at all.

Any idea what's wrong here?

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created


root@osboxes:~/kubernetes-course/dashboard# kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the pods are running under a different namespace. I had to include the namespace and then it shows the pods.

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
```